# Simple address validation with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, validation, street-address

Saw some answers here which suggest paid services or complicated address validation designs, but it doesn't apply to our specific case.

We have a lead capture form that lets users start typing the address and it autocompletes it for them:
[image]

And there's 2 common mistakes which we keep seeing:

**1) Missing door number**

**2) Missing city name (as in the screenshot)**

We're looking for a loose address verification which has room for error and that checks if there is a:

> a street number and city name in the address

We could do a simple regex to make sure there's numbers in users' input, but if we could do both using Google API that would be great.

P.S: We do display a Google map so we're not breaking their TOS by making API calls to validate the address.

> **Update:**

I was thinking of using JSON like this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=45.4993726,%20-73.5653678&sensor=false
which is returned by Google maps and does contain street numbers etc.  By door number I mean street number (it's under long_name)

Comment: Google Maps API is definitely not an address validation service. Additionally the google maps data had never included door numbers in addresses.

Comment: I was thinking of using JSON like this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=45.4993726,%20-73.5653678&sensor=false
which is returned by Google maps and does contain street numbers etc.  By door number I street number (it's under long_name)

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company called Addressy, and we offer the exact product you're looking for. It will integrate into your form in a very similar way to the Google Maps API, but we are very proud of our data quality.

Have a play around with the service [on our website](http://www.addressy.com), and see if it's for you. We offer 100  free USA lookups per month, with plans starting at $25 per month for 500 USA and Canadian lookups.

Please feel free to get in touch with me on StackOverflow or through the contact form on our website if you have any queries. :)